# Slow Data Refresh Sharepoint + excel

Tags: sharepoint-online, excel

my queries are taking a long time to update and with the sharepoint being used as a "database", I know it's not right, but it's the current scenario in the company a spreadsheet with 25 queries taking about 25~30min to upgrade. I would ask for some help or solution to decrease this update time. From what I realized the power query is making many requests for a small table and generating many requests in Sharepoint.

Comment: First you have to make sure your hardware like network speed and CPU usage is normal. I would suggest opening a ticket with MS so MS support can crawl and analyze logs for you. I think logs can tell us the truth in such performance issue.

Comment: I'll contact support

Comment: Thanks for your reply. You can share here if there is any update :)

Comment: So far I have not managed any feedback, but one of the solutions I thought was to create a data flow, I believe that excel is fighting with Sharepoint, making many requests in the API and sharepoint have a limit of access requests, the power query + power pivot configured in this excel file with the 25 queries,  end up accessing the same file multiple times. i found that using table buffer in source resolvers and disabling data visualization also did not solve the problem.